# Finding Big O of the following code

Tags: algorithm

```
i = n;
while (i >= 1){
     for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
         x++;
     i /= 2;
}
```

Answer:

```
Number of iterations = n + n/2 + n/2^2 + ... + n/2^logn
                     = n ( (1/2)^logn - 1)/ (1/2 - 1)
                     = 2n (1 - 2^(-logn))
                     < 2n
                     = O(n)
```

Question: Could anyone please explain how can we come up with the geometric sum n + n/2 + n/2^2 + ... + n/2^logn ? Thank you very much!

Comment: The first time through the outer loop i will be n, so the inner loop gets executed n times. Next time through it's n/2 because of the i/=2 line, then n/4 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two nested loops here. The outer loop starts with i equal to n and repeatedly divides i by two so long as the result is greater than or equal to 1.

The inner loop iterates over each value from 1 to i.

So the first pass through the inner loop will perform n iterations, the second n/2
the third n/4 etc.

This will continue until the last loop, when i = 1. After this, trying to divide i by 2 will yield 0 and the outer loop will terminate.

The total number of iterations of the outer loop depends on how many times we can divide n by 2.

log_2(n) is, by definition, the power by which we raise 2 to get n, i.e it is therefore the number of iterations that the outer loop will perform.